# MAC Address Filtering Fortinet v6.0

Tags: mac-address, fortigate, fortinet

I am having trouble configuring mac filtering. I do not use DHCP but am trying to figure out a way to set a mac address on a port and create a rule to block that specific mac address. So when I try and send traffic to that port, I am unable to. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What switch model(s) do you have? Also, understand that security using addresses (IP or MAC) is often worse than no security because you get a false sense of security. It is extremely easy for someone to change the MAC address on a device to be that of an allowed device. Please edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using Fortigate firewall. You can use below codes for your work

```
config firewall ipmacbinding setting
set bindthroughfw {enable | disable}  - this is enabling IPMAC binding to get through a Firewall.
set bindtofw {enable | disable}  - this will check an IP MAC binding combination to allow access TO the firewall
set undefinedhost {allow | block} - this defines how the Firewall will treat traffic that has not been bound
end


config firewall ipmacbinding table
edit <index_int> - the number in the IP/MAC binding table
set ip <address_ipv4> - IP address value
set mac <address_hex>  - MAC address value
set name <name_str> - the name which may be used for this binding
set status {enable | disable} - is the binding now enabled
end

config system interface
edit <interface name>
set ipmac {enable | disable }   - enable to enable mac binding on interface
next
end
```

In addition to that if you want to config MAC address control you can use below article which published by fortinate

[MAC control](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-managing-devices-54/MAC-acl.htm)